# Implementing Deform With Tornado

Tags: python, tornado, pyramid, deform

I am trying to build a web application with Tornado and would like to add some of the styling features from the Python package Deform. Below, I am trying to implement a user login form by combing both Tornado and Deform. However, an error is being raised: `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`.

```
class demonstrate(object):
    def __init__(self, title):
       self.title = title

   def __call__(self, method):
       method.demo = self.title
       return method
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

    self.render('/Users/jamespetullo/Downloads/studenthost-master/studentscout/home.html')
@view_defaults(route_name='student_register')
class StudentRegster(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request):
       self.request = request
       self.macros = get_renderer('templates/main.pt').implementation().macros
   def render_form(self, form, appstruct=colander.null, submitted='submit',
                success=None, readonly=False, is_i18n=False):

       captured = None

       if submitted in self.request.POST:

           try:
               controls = self.request.POST.items()
               captured = form.validate(controls)
               if success:
                   response = success()
                   if response is not None:
                      return response
               html = form.render(captured)
            except deform.ValidationFailure as e:
                            html = e.render()

       else:
            html = form.render(appstruct, readonly=readonly)

      if self.request.is_xhr:
          return Response(html)

      code, start, end = self.get_code(2)
      locale_name = get_locale_name(self.request)

      reqts = form.get_widget_resources()

      printer = pprint.PrettyPrinter(width=1)
      printer.format = my_safe_repr
      output = printer.pformat(captured)
      captured = highlight(output,
                         PythonLexer(),
                         formatter)

    # values passed to template for rendering
      return {
        'form':html,
        'captured': captured,
        'code': code,
        'start':start,
        'end':end,
        'is_i18n':is_i18n,
        'locale': locale_name,
        'demos':self.get_demos(),
        'title':self.get_title(),
        'css_links':reqts['css'],
        'js_links':reqts['js'],
        }
   @view_config(renderer='templates/form.pt', name='edit')
   @demonstrate('Edit Form')
   def get(self):


       import datetime

       class Mapping(colander.Schema):
          name = colander.SchemaNode(
             colander.String(),
             description='Content name')
          date = colander.SchemaNode(
            colander.Date(),
            widget=deform.widget.DatePartsWidget(),
            description='Content date')

       class Schema(colander.Schema):
           number = colander.SchemaNode(
            colander.Integer())
            mapping = Mapping()

       schema = Schema()
       form = deform.Form(schema, buttons=('submit',))
       appstruct = {
        'number': 42,
        'mapping': {
            'date': datetime.date(2010, 4, 9),
            }
        }

       return self.render_form(form, appstruct=appstruct)
```

My main issue is that I am unable to combine the Tornado `get` method and serve the deform templates. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Please let me know of any questions you have.

Edit:

Here is the full traceback:

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado/http1connection.py",   line 238, in _read_message
delegate.finish()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado/routing.py", line 251, in finish
self.delegate.finish()
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2096, in finish
 self.execute()
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 2116, in execute
 **self.handler_kwargs)
 TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: Can you share a traceback? That will reveal which line passes the wrong number of arguments to a class's \_\_init\_\_ method.

Comment: @A.JesseJiryuDavis please see my recent edit.

Comment: The traceback is too vague. But if I have to guess, I'd say that as you've decorated the `StudentRegister` handler with `@view_defaults`, this decorator is passing an extra argument to `StudentRegister`, but as you can see, it's `__init__` only takes two arguments. I think you should try changing it to something like `__init__(self, request, *args)` and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you override `__init__`, be sure to match the superclass's signature (and call `super().__init__(*args, **kw)`). In this case `RequestHandler.__init__()` takes two arguments, the application and request objects. Or if you'd rather not think about matching the superclass's `__init__` signature (which you shouldn't really know/care about anyway since these objects are constructed by the framework), you can override `initialize()` instead (this method is provided by `RequestHandler` specifically so you don't have to worry about the subtleties of overriding `__init__()`)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I tried your solution above, and it appears that it has fixed the `TypeError`; however, I am now getting an error message that is related to the template rendering: `ValueError: No such renderer factory .pt`. Do you have any suggestions as to how this could be fixed?

`

Comment: What's `get_renderer`? There's no import for it in your sample. I'm unfamiliar with whatever package is providing this function.